# nav text displays outside of div

Tags: html, css, web, nav

The navigation for my website is displaying outside my header, and nothing I do is working. I want the text to be inside .header and be on the right side. It's probably some stupid and simple mistake, but I can't seem to find it. Live demo of problem here: http://codecat.pancakeapps.com/index.html

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Codecat - Hand crafted websites for affordable prices</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://codecat.pancakeapps.com/index.html">
    <Codecat>
    </a>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>BIO</li>
        <li>COMMISIONS</li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
</div>    
</div>
<div class="about">
Welcome to Codecat! I am an independent web designer that makes hand crafted websites on commision for affordable prices. My last three projects are listed below, (to the owners expense) so look around!
</div>
<div class="one">
<h1>Blinders Journal</h1>
<span class="progress">(In Progress)</span>
<article>
<span class="link">
    <a href="http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/index.html">
http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/index.html
    </a>
</span>
<br />
<p>Have you ever, as a new writer, felt intimidated by the contributor bios you read in the back of your favorite magazines? Have you ever, as a well-established writer, wondered how well your manuscripts would fare if they were separated from your name and list of previous publications?</p>

<p>We here at Blinders Literary Journal hope that we have found a solution for writers and poets, new and advanced. We read blind submissions only for two electronic issues a year, one to be published in summer and one in winter. We never want to see your cover letter, only your fiction, creative nonfiction, poetry, and artwork.</p>

<p>Once we accept your work, we will display it professionally in a digital environment. Also, upon acceptance, your name will become important to us. We will pay the highest respect possible to our contributors.</p> 
</article>
</div>
<div class="two">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<span class="progress">(Done)</span>
<article>
<span class="link">http://consectetuer.adipiscing.elit.com</span>
<br />
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.</p>
</article>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Orson Heavy;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/sf-orson-casual.heavy.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Timeburner;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/timeburner_regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Icecream;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/ICE-CS__.TTF');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Nordic;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/PTF-NORDIC-Rnd.ttf');
}
.header {
background: #000;
height: 60px;
}
.logo {
font-family: Orson Heavy;
font-size: 40px;
color: #0f0;
margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
background: url('http://www.dreamwidth.org/img/styles/planetcaravan/starrysky.png');
}
.one, .two {
background: #000;
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: 120px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
h1 {
font-family: Icecream;
font-size: 40px;
color: yellow;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
article {
font-family: Verdana;
color: #fff;
font-size 10px;
}
.progress {
color: yellow;
font-size 14px;
font-family: Timeburner;
}
.link {
color: yellow;
}
.about {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: 120px;
margin-top: 20px; 
color: green;
font-size: 21px;
font-family: Timeburner;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: yellow;
}
.logo a {
color: green;
}
nav {
font-family: Nordic;
font-size: 30;
color: green;
}
ul {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none; 
}
li {
float: left; 
}
```

**EDIT**
something happened and now the logo glitches through the top of the page and replaces the nav.
I have no idea what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question completely  but try adding this in your css  http://jsfiddle.net/jc9w670r/ (increase the output area to see the result in a better way)

```
.logo nav{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: @8bitcodecat what exactly do you want then? when i tried your code in jsfiddle as the logo goes right the BIO and COMMISSIONS get into the header

Comment: That's when I added **your** code, I want the bio and commissions to go to the right while the logo stays where it is. @Akshay

Comment: That's closer @Akshay, but the logo is now glitching through the top of the  screen and the nav is partially cut off.

Comment: @8bitcodecat everything seems to be fine in jsfiddle did you check the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60784/discussion-between-akshay-and-8bitcodecat).

Comment: @Akshay - what happen ?

Comment: @Singh nothing i didn't understand your question at first but i got it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60785/discussion-between-akshay-and-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css code and it may help for you.In your code i have changed `ul li` style and set margin according to logo with align-right.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/576fgm72/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://codecat.pancakeapps.com/index.html">
    &#60;Codecat&#62;
    </a>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>BIO</li>
        <li>COMMISIONS</li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
</div>    
</div>
<div class="about">
Welcome to Codecat! I am an independent web designer that makes hand crafted websites on commision for affordable prices. My last three projects are listed below, (to the owners expense) so look around!
</div>
<div class="one">
<h1>Blinders Journal</h1>
<span class="progress">(In Progress)</span>
<article>
<span class="link">
    <a href="http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/index.html">
http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/index.html
    </a>
</span>
<br />
<p>Have you ever, as a new writer, felt intimidated by the contributor bios you read in the back of your favorite magazines? Have you ever, as a well-established writer, wondered how well your manuscripts would fare if they were separated from your name and list of previous publications?</p>

<p>We here at Blinders Literary Journal hope that we have found a solution for writers and poets, new and advanced. We read blind submissions only for two electronic issues a year, one to be published in summer and one in winter. We never want to see your cover letter, only your fiction, creative nonfiction, poetry, and artwork.</p>

<p>Once we accept your work, we will display it professionally in a digital environment. Also, upon acceptance, your name will become important to us. We will pay the highest respect possible to our contributors.</p> 
</article>
</div>
<div class="two">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<span class="progress">(Done)</span>
<article>
<span class="link">http://consectetuer.adipiscing.elit.com</span>
<br />
<p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.</p>
</article>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
@font-face {
font-family: Orson Heavy;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/sf-orson-casual.heavy.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Timeburner;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/timeburner_regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Icecream;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/ICE-CS__.TTF');
}
@font-face {
font-family: Nordic;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/PTF-NORDIC-Rnd.ttf');
}
.header {
background: #000;
height: 60px;
}
.logo {
font-family: Orson Heavy;
font-size: 40px;
color: #0f0;
margin-left: 10px;
position:relative;
float;left;
}
nav ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:-39px;
}
body {
background: url('http://www.dreamwidth.org/img/styles/planetcaravan/starrysky.png');
}
.one, .two {
background: #000;
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: 120px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
h1 {
font-family: Icecream;
font-size: 40px;
color: yellow;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
article {
font-family: Verdana;
color: #fff;
font-size 10px;
}
.progress {
color: yellow;
font-size 14px;
font-family: Timeburner;
}
.link {
color: yellow;
}
.about {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: 120px;
margin-top: 20px; 
color: green;
font-size: 21px;
font-family: Timeburner;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: yellow;
}
.logo a {
color: green;
}
nav {
font-family: Nordic;
font-size: 30;
color: green;
}
ul {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none; 
}
li {
float: left; 
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]